# More efficient way to handle an extremely specific response from a Rest API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, rest

I'm working with a Dungeons & Dragons 5e API and want that an especific result be treated in a special way. The user can choose what to search from a range of options, and in only one of them would I need to take care of the answer in a different way. In this option, I get the answer in JSON that contains a 'name' field, which stores a String, but in this specific case this String comes with an acronym, and I would like to transform it into the full name.I'm afraid to just put am 'if' statement in the middle of the code and deal with the situation inefficiently, even more so that I did not find similar situations to have any reference.

This is part of the result of the API I want to handle in a special way:

```
{"count":6,
 "results":[
    {"name":"STR",
     "url":"http://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/ability-score/1"},
    {"name":"DEX",
     "url":"http://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/ability-scores2"},
    ....
    ]
 }
```

This is how I handle the answer:

```
fetch(fullAPIURL)
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(data => {
        let resultContainer = document.getElementById('resultContainer');

        //Cleaning the result container from previous results
        document.querySelectorAll('#resultContainer article').forEach(container =>
            resultContainer.removeChild(container));

        spanSearchResult.classList.remove('invisible', 'searchFail');
        spanSearchResult.classList.add('searchSucess');

        spanSearchResult.innerHTML = `Search returned ${data.count} results`;

        for (element of data.results) {
            let containerTitle = element.name != undefined ? element.name : element.class;
            resultContainer.appendChild(createResultContainer(containerTitle));
        }

    })
    .catch(err => {
        spanSearchResult.classList.remove('invisible');
        spanSearchResult.classList.add('searchFail');
        spanSearchResult.innerHTML = 'Something went wrong! Details in the console';

        console.log(err);
    });
```

Is putting a condition in this snippet of code really the most efficient way to solve this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just make a lookup call, actually. In fact, that'd be preferable if you ever want to port your application to another language, for example.

Define the following:

```js
var retrieve = (function() {
  var items = {
    "STR": "Strength",
    "DEX": "Dexterity"
  };
  return function(item) {
    return items[item] || item;
  }
})();
    
console.log(retrieve("DEX"));
```

With this, you can simply call `retrieve(element.name)` to retrieve its "actual" name. You can add elements to the object to create new translations, and if you ever need to support multiple languages, you can even replace the function entirely.

Comment: Different way to think, very nice! Worked perfectly